# MySQL comparing date string into date column

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM tracklogs.sms_outbound
WHERE gsmno = 'rk4@*******.com.ph'
AND cdate > cast('2013/11/14 09:44:48 PM' as datetime)
```

where cdate format is in `%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p`.

I have tried converting the date into that format then cast it as datetime but still doesn't working.

Comment: you shouldn't need to cast it. MySQL recognizes strings as dates if they are in ISO format. You may need to convert your `9:44 PM` to 24-hour time though.

Comment: What version of MySQL? Before 5.6.4 fractional seconds weren't supported in DATETIME variables.  What is the data type of `cdate`?

Comment: cdate is in date format %Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tracklogs.sms_outbound 
WHERE gsmno = 'rk4@*******.com.ph' 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(str_to_date(cdate,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-14 09:44:48')
```

Comment: but the greater then operator doesn't work with the time

Comment: Ummm, you lost the PM in this answer.

Comment: please try @user3094947

Comment: I recommend explaining what your code snippet does.

Answer (score 2):

Use `STR_TO_DATE()` to correctly convert the datetime literal you have provided to a proper `DATETIME` value. It seems that your `cdate` column is a `char()` or `varchar()` column. So you will also need to convert that to `DATETIME` to compare it.

What you need is this:

That works like this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/48741/0)

```
STR_TO_DATE(cdate, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s %p') >
 STR_TO_DATE('2013/11/14 09:44:48 PM', '%Y/%m/%d %h:%i:%s %p')
```

Converting these strings to `DATETIME` data items ensures that the comparison handles both the date and the time correctly. See this fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/48743/0)

But, you should consider changing your `cdate` item to a `DATETIME`, because then you'll be able to index it and speed up your search.